# How to search multiple fields of an access database in VB using code

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, vba

I have created a program which displays data from different tables in an access database(without the use of wizards to connect to the database. i.e. all connection have been hard coded), I have created a simple search which searches through one field in one table. However I would like to make a function which allows me to search through all of the fields in a table. Below is the simple search function I have created.

```
     Public Sub Search()         
    con.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Table1")
    Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table1 where FirstName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'", con)

    rs.Fill(dt)
    dgvTabel2.DataSource = dt
    dgvTabel2.Refresh()

    rs.Dispose()
    con.Close()  
     end sub
```

The new function should look something like this

```
   Public Sub SearchHard(TableName As String)
    con.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("TableName")
    Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(("Select * from " & TableName & " where FirstName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'") Or ("Select * from " & TableName & " where LastName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "')"), con)
    'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FirstName LIKE '% txtTable1.text %' OR LastName LIKE '%txtTable1.tetx%'

    rs.Fill(dt)
    dgvTabel1.DataSource = dt
    dgvTabel1.Refresh()

    rs.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

It would also be a big plus if the function could accept a parameter to select a different table to reduce overusing the code.
Any and all help would be much appreciated

Working code to with searches.

```
    con.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Table1")
    Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  Table1  WHERE (FirstName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "') or (LastName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "')", con)
    rs.Fill(dt)
    dgvTabel1.DataSource = dt
    dgvTabel1.Refresh()

    rs.Dispose()
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some wrong quotes in there:

```
"Select * from Table where Field1 = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'" or Field2 = '" & txtTabel1.Text"'"
```

should be

```
"Select * from Table where Field1 = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "' or Field2 = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'"
```

Now of course you could use your parameter `TableName` like this

```
"Select * from " & TableName & " where Field1 = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'"
```

But different tables will have different field names, so that wouldn't really work. In the end you'd have to add lots of parameters and sort of re-invent SQL.

A better solution would be to pass the full SQL SELECT string to your function.

Comment: @ Andre451 Thank you very much, the standard search with a parameter is working, however when I add an or it gives an error "Conversion from string "Select * from Table1 where First" to type 'Long' is not valid." pointing at "rs.fill(dt). New code =(("Select * from " & TableName & " where FirstName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "'") Or ("Select * from " & TableName & " where LastName = '" & txtTabel1.Text & "')"), con)

Comment: @Tyler_Coder: It's not `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = 'x') OR (SELECT * FROM table WHERE field2 = 'x')`, but `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1 = 'x') OR (field2 = 'x')`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help and bearing with me through all of my mistakes, I have finally fixed my problems and everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what was already mentioned here by @andre451, you could use `union` if you want to search multiple tables

```sql
SELECT field_1 , field_2
FROM table_1
WHERE field_3 = 'value' or field_4 = 'value'
UNION [ALL]
SELECT field_100 , field_200
FROM table_2
WHERE field_300 = 'value' or field_400 = 'value'
```

As long as your `field_1` and `field_100` match data types and count of fields matches